# Passing parameters to nested workflow

Tags: powershell

If I have the following code, is it possible to pass the collection of parameters passed to New-AutomationVM to the inner Deploy workflow without individually specifying them.

New-AutomationVM is likely to have ~20 parameters, and that is going to be a considerable piece of code to then integrate into a second internal workflow. (that seems vulnerable to errors)

Is there a better way? (I'm sure at some point I've read about all parameters being included in a psobject style variable, but I can't find a reference to it any more)

```
workflow New-AutomationVM
{
    Param($var1,$var2)
    workflow Pre-DeploymentChecks
    { Write-Output $true }

    workflow Deploy 
    {
        Param($var1,$var2)
        $checkResult = Pre-DeploymentChecks 
    }

    Deploy -var1 $var1 -var2 $var2 
}
New-AutomationVM -var1 "var1" -var2 "var2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know. The usual solution would be `Deploy @PSBoundParameters`, but neither `$PSBoundParameters` or splatting are availble in a workflow.

> Splatting is not permitted in workflow activities or in calls to
>   workflows.

Source: [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/nb-no/library/jj574140.aspx)

> All Windows PowerShell automatic variables are valid in workflows,
>   except for the automatic variables in the following list. For a
>   complete list of automatic variables, see about_Automatic_Variables.
>
> •$Args
>
> •$Error
>
> •$MyInvocation
>
> •$PID
>
> •**$PSBoundParameters**
>
> •$PsCmdlet
>
> •$PSCommandPath
>
> •$PSScriptRoot
>
> •$StackTrace

Source: [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/nb-no/library/jj574187.aspx)

Comment: `$PSBoundParameters` does not work within workflows.